# Random number when allocation struct integer (int) in C

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm allocating dynamically the amount of ram that I will need for my program. It is working fine until I came across this problem. This is when I type the content that is going to be inside of my one item that is inside the struct which is referred to as an Integer if I type more than 10 number for example (12345678912) it will send me back, a completely different number.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cadastro
{
char email[50];
char nome[20];
int idade;
int telefone;
};

int main()
{
int quantidade_cadastros;
int decisao = 1;

printf("\nQuantos cadastros deseja realizar?\n");
printf("Quantidade: ");
scanf("%d", &quantidade_cadastros);
getchar();

//Definindo a quantidade de cadastros que podem ser realizados no struct e o nome que sera usado para chamar o struct
struct cadastro *cad;
cad = NULL;

cad = malloc(quantidade_cadastros * sizeof(struct cadastro));

for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_cadastros; i++)
{
    printf("\nDigite o NOME da pessoa que sera inserida no indice %d: ", i);
    fgets(cad[i].nome, 20, stdin);
    printf("Digite o EMAIL da pessoa que sera inserida no indice %d: ", i);
    fgets(cad[i].email, 50, stdin);
    printf("Digite a IDADE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &cad[i].idade);
    getchar();
    printf("Digite o TELEFONE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &cad[i].telefone);
    getchar();
}

for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_cadastros; i++)
{
    printf("\nNOME: %s", cad[i].nome);
    printf("EMAIL: %s", cad[i].email);
    printf("IDADE: %d", cad[i].idade);
    printf("\nTELEFONE: %d", cad[i].telefone);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n");
free(cad);
}
```

Here is the input I entered:

```
Quantos cadastros deseja realizar?
Quantidade: 2

Digite o NOME da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 0: Test1
Digite o EMAIL da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 0: Email1
Digite a IDADE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 0: 19
Digite o TELEFONE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 0: 1234567891

Digite o NOME da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 1: Test2
Digite o EMAIL da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 1: Email2
Digite a IDADE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 1: 18
Digite o TELEFONE da pessoa que sera inserida no indice 1: 12345678912

NOME: Test1
EMAIL: Email1
IDADE: 19
TELEFONE: 1234567891

NOME: Test2
EMAIL: Email2
IDADE: 18
TELEFONE: -539222976
```

Comment: What's the largest number an int can hold on your system?

Comment: @Eraklon No because i'm not trying to generate number, I want to know why does it output a complete different number from what I typed

Comment: It was a misclick. But this is a duplicate nonetheless. Read about integer overflow.

Comment: @Eraklon I searched up about int, and I saw it can store at max of 'The highest signed value would be 2^31 which is 2,147,483,648.' Does this answer my own question?

Comment: 12,345,678,912 > 2,147,483,648 ---> integer overflow, if you search the term you will know whats wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an int overflow. The second 'phone number' you typed in is larger than an int can store, and you are not verifying the reading. The `scanf` probably failed, and stored nothing in the int - which means there is still random bits in its memory area, as you never cleared it. The `printf` then prints those random information.

You should *always* verify that `scanf` was successful - it will return the number of successfully assigned fields, here `1`. So you should use `if (scanf(...) != 1) { /*handle error*/ }, instead of ignoring it.